# Concept of compiler created default constructor

Tags: c++

I have seen this line so many times i.e. "When no constructor is **defined** then compiler supplies its own default constructor". So i tried to understand it from the following code. 
 
This code is doing addition of two complex numbers.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

class complex
{
    float x,y;
    public:

    complex(){}
    complex(float a)
    {
        x=y=a;
    }
    complex(float real,float imag)
    {
        x=real;
        y=imag;
    }

    friend complex sum(complex,complex);

    friend void show(complex);
};

complex sum(complex a,complex b)
{
    complex c;
    c.x=a.x+b.x;
    c.y=a.y+b.y;
     return(c);
 }

 void show(complex c)
 {
    cout<<c.x<<"+j"<<c.y<<endl;
 }

int main()
{

    complex A(2);
    complex B(4,5);
    complex C;

    C=sum(A,B);

    show(A);
    show(B);
    show(C);

    return 0;
}
```

Here i have written `complex C` in `int main()` function. So this object initializes with the help of `complex(){}` written in class `complex`.
But when i remove this `complex(){}` and execute the code, then it gives an error. 
 
 Then according to the definition, why compiler doesn't created its own constructor? 
 
I have searched so many similar questions related to default constructors but could not find answer to mine.

Comment: Do note that the compiler's default constructor will cause UB if you read from the data members after.

Comment: _why compiler doesn't created its own constructor?_  Because "When no constructor is defined then compiler supplies its own default constructor".  You only deleted the default constructor, you did not delete the other constructors.

Comment: The compiler doesn't generate a default constructor if you provide your own.

Comment: _"I have seen this line so many times"_  but apparently never read it carefully.

Comment: To clarify my other comment, just in case, it will *in this case* since the members are `float`.

Answer (score 3):

Read the quote carefully.

> When no constructor is defined then compiler supplies its own default constructor

This doesn't say "if you don't define a default constructor, you get one automatically". It says "if you don't define *any* constructor, you get a default one automatically". So your `complex(float)` and `complex(float, float)` constructors are blocking the creation of the default one.

Note that if you want a compiler-generated default constructor in addition to some other constructors you define, on C++11 and beyond you can explicitly create one.

```
class complex {
  complex() = default;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the C++11 Standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.ctor#5) (emphasis mine):

> A *default* constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` that can be called without an argument. **If there is no user-declared constructor for class `X`**, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted.

The implied default constructor is not created when there are any other user-declared constructors.

If you have the following constructors

```
complex(float a);
complex(float real,float imag);
```

the implied default constructor is not created.